# Not Working Fingerprint scanner for x360 1030 g2 hp notebook with ubuntu 19.10

Tags: hp, 19.10

I had [x360 1030 G2](https://store.hp.com/us/en/tech-takes/hp-elitebook-x360-1030-g2-laptop-complete-review) laptop and I have installed ubuntu 19.10 
When I used windows 10, My fingerprint scanner was worked. Official site of HP laptop manual also they have mentioned that this notebook has a fingerprint scanner. 
I couldn't get the scanner setting in ubuntu. I have used this https://www.madtrickz.com/2017/11/how-to-setup-fingerprint-lock-in-ubuntu.html page to setup the fingerprint GUI. In there, I don't have devices.

I used

```
sudo lshw -short
```

I could not get my device.
If anyone has a solution for this, please share with me. It will help a lot me